# Агрегирование элементов списка в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан список:

```
[
  (421827102, 100, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  (421827102,   1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  (422826102, 100, 0, 0, 1, 0),
]
```

Как эффективно сгруппировать все кортежи по первому элементу и сложить остальные элементы в каждой группе?

В данном случае должен получиться список:

```
[
  (421827102, 101, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  (422826102, 100, 0, 0, 1, 0),
]
```

Comment: а почему у вас в результате в первой группе получается `(421827102, 101, 0, 0, 1, 0)`, а не `(421827102, 101, 0, 0, 2, 0)` ?

Comment: Там суть была была про 2 число. Мне изменили тему.

Comment: @СашаРоманов, нужно все числа складывать (от второго и до пятого) или только вторые?

Comment: только вторые числа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще сделать через pandas, мне кажется:

Исходные:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [
  (421827102, 100, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  (421827102,   1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  (422826102, 100, 0, 0, 1, 0),
]
```

Группируем:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df.groupby(0).sum().reset_index())
```

Получаем:

```
           0    1  2  3  4  5
0  421827102  101  0  0  2  0
1  422826102  100  0  0  1  0
```

Либо в виде списка списков:

```
print(df.groupby(0).sum().reset_index().values.tolist())
#[[421827102, 101, 0, 0, 2, 0], [422826102, 100, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: я с данной библиотекой не знаком, поэтому как по мне легче без pandas.

Answer (score 4):

Например, можно группировать через словарь:

```
items = [
    (421827102, 100, 0, 0, 1, 0),
    (421827102,   1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
    (422826102, 100, 0, 0, 1, 0),
]

data = dict()
for x in items:
    if x[0] not in data:
        data[x[0]] = list(x)
    else:
        values = data[x[0]]
        values[1] += x[1]

print(data)
# {421827102: [421827102, 101, 0, 0, 1, 0], 422826102: [422826102, 100, 0, 0, 1, 0]}

new_items = list(data.values())
print(new_items)
# [[421827102, 101, 0, 0, 1, 0], [422826102, 100, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

---

**UPD.**

Обновил ответ для суммирования всех чисел, а не только на второй позиции:

```
items = [
    (421827102, 100, 0, 0, 1, 0),
    (421827102,   1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
    (422826102, 100, 0, 0, 1, 0),
]

data = dict()
for x in items:
    if x[0] not in data:
        data[x[0]] = list(x)
    else:
        values = data[x[0]]

        for i in range(1, len(x)):
            values[i] += x[i]

print(data)
# {421827102: [421827102, 101, 0, 0, 2, 0], 422826102: [422826102, 100, 0, 0, 1, 0]}

new_items = list(data.values())
print(new_items)
# [[421827102, 101, 0, 0, 2, 0], [422826102, 100, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

---

**PS.**

Думаю, не страшно, что вместо кортежа там стал использоваться список.
Просто, кортеж, в отличии от списка не редактируемый

Comment: если нет одинаковых он сам с собой складывает

Comment: @СашаРоманов, не будет складывать для не одинаковых. Для не одинаковых, код пройдет в `if x[0] not in data:` а там нет складывания. Для одинаковых код всегда будет идти в `else:`